# Merge more similar JS functions

Tags: javascript

I managed to write this JS code but I'm pretty sure that I could write it down in a better way because I'm using 5 different functions but are really similar so I was wondering if there is a better way (with less code) to write these functions:

HTML:

```
<div class="news-wrap margin-top-div">
  <div class="news-btn-container-flex">
    <div class="news-btn-div current" data-tab="1" onclick="req1()">1</div>
    <div class="news-btn-div" data-tab="2" onclick="req2()">2</div>
    <div class="news-btn-div" data-tab="3" onclick="req3()">3</div>
    <div class="news-btn-div" data-tab="4" onclick="req4()">4</div>
    <div class="news-btn-div" data-tab="5" onclick="req5()">5</div>       
  </div>

  <div class="news-content-container-flex">
    <div class="news-title">
      <span id="newsTitle">
      </span>
    </div>
    <div id="content-news">
    </div>
  </div>       

</div>
```

JS:

```
function req1() {
  fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1')
    .then(function (res) {return res.json()})
    .then(function (json) {
      var title = json.title;
      var body = "";
      var i = 0;
      while (i <= 5) {
          body += json.body;
          i++;
      }
      document.getElementById("newsTitle").innerHTML = title;
      document.getElementById("content-news").innerHTML = body;
    });
}
req1();

function req2() {
  fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/2')
    .then(function (res) {return res.json()})
    .then(function (json) {
      var title = json.title;
      var body = "";
      var i = 0;
      while (i <= 5) {
          body += json.body;
          i++;
      }
      document.getElementById("newsTitle").innerHTML = title;
      document.getElementById("content-news").innerHTML = body;
    });
}

function req3() {
  fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/3')
    .then(function (res) {return res.json()})
    .then(function (json) {
      var title = json.title;
      var body = "";
      var i = 0;
      while (i <= 5) {
          body += json.body;
          i++;
      }
      document.getElementById("newsTitle").innerHTML = title;
      document.getElementById("content-news").innerHTML = body;
    });
}

function req4() {
  fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/4')
    .then(function (res) {return res.json()})
    .then(function (json) {
      var title = json.title;
      var body = "";
      var i = 0;
      while (i <= 5) {
          body += json.body;
          i++;
      }
      document.getElementById("newsTitle").innerHTML = title;
      document.getElementById("content-news").innerHTML = body;
    });
}

function req5() {
  fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/5')
    .then(function (res) {return res.json()})
    .then(function (json) {
      var title = json.title;
      var body = "";
      var i = 0;
      while (i <= 5) {
          body += json.body;
          i++;
      }
      document.getElementById("newsTitle").innerHTML = title;
      document.getElementById("content-news").innerHTML = body;
    });
}
```

As you can see there is probably too much code and too many repetitions so I'd like to shrink as much as possible without using new features like ES6 in order to avoid problems on old browsers.

Any advice?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can simply do it by passing an argument which will contain the value to be appended in url in a function and use that function in every click event like this

```js
function req(id) {
  fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/' + id)
    .then(function(res) {
      return res.json()
    })
    .then(function(json) {
      var title = json.title;
      var body = "";
      var i = 0;
      while (i <= 5) {
        body += json.body;
        i++;
      }
      document.getElementById("newsTitle").innerHTML = title;
      document.getElementById("content-news").innerHTML = body;
    });
}
req(1);
```

```html
<div class="news-wrap margin-top-div">
  <div class="news-btn-container-flex">
    <div class="news-btn-div current" data-tab="1" onclick="req(1)">1</div>
    <div class="news-btn-div" data-tab="2" onclick="req(2)">2</div>
    <div class="news-btn-div" data-tab="3" onclick="req(3)">3</div>
    <div class="news-btn-div" data-tab="4" onclick="req(4)">4</div>
    <div class="news-btn-div" data-tab="5" onclick="req(5)">5</div>
  </div>

  <div class="news-content-container-flex">
    <div class="news-title">
      <span id="newsTitle">
      </span>
    </div>
    <div id="content-news">
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Just one more thing that I forgot to mention in the question, as you can see I put req1(); at the end of the first function because I want to print the first one on page load (as default). In your function, should I just ad req1(); at the end to get the first post as default?

Comment: No you need to add req(1) at the end to get the first post as default.

Comment: Fantastic! Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

Simply pass the ID as function argument

```
function req( id ) {
  fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/' + id)
    .then(function (res) {return res.json()})
    .then(function (json) {
      var title = json.title;
      var body = "";
      var i = 0;
      while (i <= 5) {
          body += json.body;
          i++;
      }
      document.getElementById("newsTitle").innerHTML = title;
      document.getElementById("content-news").innerHTML = body;
    });
}
```

Use like:

```
req( 5 );
```